# Get keys from object as numeric in javascript

Tags: javascript

If I use

```
a = {2: "test", 3: "test2"};
console.log(Object.keys(a));
```

I will get a list `["2", "3"]`. Can I get these as numeric elements instead of string elements?

Comment: console.log(Object.keys(a).map(Number)); ?

Comment: Exactly. Put it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

Make use of `map()` to achieve what you want.

```
console.log(Object.keys(a).map(Number));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ES6, [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) has support for numeric keys:

```
var m = new Map();
m.set(2, "test");
m.set(3, "test2");
console.log([...myMap.keys()]);
```